# Node JS Require Works Initially Only (debugging)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, require

I'm getting a bit confused on how to properly utilize the Node JS require.

I have a Node Webkit application which spawns children windows, each child window will need to read and write data to a sqlite3 database.

In my index.html I have a button to create an iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
   var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
   console.log(sqlite3);
</script>

<body>

   <!-- CREATE NEW APP IF NEEDED -->
   <button onclick="spawnApp()">Spawn App</button>

   <div id="containApp">

      <!-- RUN INITIAL APP -->
      <iframe src="apps/sub.html"></iframe>

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The spawnApp() is a function in a index.js file

```
function spawnApp() {

   var varIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
   varIframe.src = "apps/sub.html";

   var varContainer = document.getElementById("containApp");
   varContainer.appendChild(varIframe);

}
```

The app it spawns is called sub.html which is needed to make a database connection to sqlite3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
   var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
   console.log(sqlite3);
</script>

<body>

   <h4>Sub App</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

When I execute the program for the first time it seems to work perfectly as I get the following output in the console.

```
> Object                                                   index.html:9
> Object                                                     sub.html:6
```

Which is what I expected, an object is created from require on the index.html and then the initial sub.html which is an iframe written statically into the index.html.

However one I click the button to add a new app I get the following error

```
> Object                                                   index.html:9
> Object                                                     sub.html:6
> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined            sub.html:5
```

What else is weird is that if I hit the refresh button I get a similar error without even using the button to create a new app.

```
> Object {...}                                             index.html:9
> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined            sub.html:5
```

I have no idea what is causing this and I've spent so much time trying to figure it out, why does the require only work on the initial program launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the reason for this and a work around.

I was reading through some Node Q&A Forums and it seems that Node does not actually support iframe and therefore there is some unexpected behavior when calling node modules.

The work around though (which might not suit everyone's needs) is simply to use divs instead and use some jQuery/Javascript to write the elements from the sub.html into the div instead.

Not a great work around but I'm working on an HTML generator to significantly speed up the generation of the HTML content which will make the workaround more valid.